# How to express the following statement with Quantifiers and Predicates

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Use quantifiers and predicates with more than one variable to express this statement:

> There is a student in this class who has taken every course offered by one of the departments in this school

I know there are many ways we can express a single statement with logical symbols but I'd like to know if the solution I came up with needs to be corrected, because sometimes I am confused dealing with the domain of the variable

---

My solution:

*T*(x, y) denotes "x have taken y" where the domain of x consists only of students and y is a course

*O*(y, z) denotes "y is a course of the department z" where z is a department of the school

> **∃x ∀y ∃z (*T*(x, y) ∧ *O*(y, z))**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

> There is a student in this class who has taken every course offered by one of the departments in this school

could be "worded" more clearly. I take it to mean that there is some student $x$ and there is some ("one") department $z$, such that $x$ has taken every course $y$ offered by $z$:
$$\exists x\,\exists z\,\forall y\,(O(y,z) \to T(x,y)). \tag{1}
$$
Notice that in the highlighted English sentence, the "every course" quantifier *precedes* the department quantifier ("one of the departments"), the opposite of their order in the logical structure.

You didn't symbolize "in this class", so I didn't either in (1), but you should. To keep it simple, let $C(x)$" stand for "$x$ is in this class". A better rendering:
$$\exists x\, \big( C(x) \land \exists z\,\forall y\,(O(y,z) \to T(x,y)) \big). \tag{2}
$$
The "domain" over which variables range is a little unusual for a basic logic example but quite typical of "real-world" situations. It's most naturally thought of as multi-sorted: there are students, departments, and courses, so the actual universe of the interpretation is the disjoint union of these sets. In the intended interpretation of $T$, if $T(x,y)[\mathbf{a}/x, \mathbf{b}/y ]$ is true, then $\mathbf{a}$ is a student and $\mathbf{b}$ is a course; similarly, $O(y,z)[\mathbf{b}/y, \mathbf{c}/z ]$ is true only of courses $\mathbf{b}$ and departments $\mathbf{c}$.

---

Your statement is very different than what the English sentence (tries to) express. Your rendering:
$$\exists x\,\forall y\,\exists z\,(T(x,y) \land O(y,z))
$$
is equivalent to:
$$\exists x\,\forall y\,T(x,y) \land \forall y\,\exists z\,O(y,z)
$$
which says: there's a student who has taken every course, and every course is offered by some department — two independent statements.